# How to filter the columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2005

I want to filter the column where column value not equal to numeric

Table1

```
Status

010203
Absent
231415
Ramesh
Suresh

...,
```

I want to get only Names from the status column like

Tried Query

```
Select Status from table1 where status <> 'absent' and status <> numecivalue
```

How to mentioned status <> numericvalue

Expected Output

```
Table

Status

Ramesh
Suresh
...,
```

Need Query Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [ISNUMERIC(expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT t.status 
  FROM table1 t 
 WHERE t.status != 'absent' 
   AND ISNUMERIC(t.status) != 1
```

Reference: [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    status 
FROM 
    table1 
WHERE 
    status  <> 'absent' AND 
    ISNUMERIC(status) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this weblos ..............

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/10/18/SQL-Server-Filtering-Numeric-data-from-a-character-based-column.aspx

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsNumericEx( @value nvarchar(max) )
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
         DECLARE @isInt BIT

         SELECT  @isInt = 1 
         WHERE   @value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%'
                 AND LEN(REPLACE(@value, '.', '')) >= LEN(@value) - 1
                 AND CHARINDEX('-', @value) IN (0, 1)
                 AND CHARINDEX('-', @value, 2) = 0

         RETURN ISNULL(@isInt, 0)
END
GO

DECLARE @t1 TABLE (title varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @t1
SELECT '123d456' UNION ALL
SELECT '12 3456' UNION ALL
SELECT '123456' UNION ALL
SELECT '1234-56' UNION ALL
SELECT '123456-' UNION ALL
SELECT '-123456' UNION ALL
SELECT '-123-456' UNION ALL
SELECT 'dddfaf56' UNION ALL
SELECT '5532.673' UNION ALL
SELECT '5532673.' UNION ALL
SELECT '.5532.673'

SELECT   *
FROM     @t1
WHERE    dbo.IsNumericEx(title) = 0

SELECT   *
FROM     @t1
WHERE    dbo.IsNumericEx(title) = 1

GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.IsNumericEx
```

Comment: If you post code, be it T-SQL or whatever, PLEASE use the code button (010 101) in the editor toolbar to format them as code, so that they are nicely readable and will get syntax highlighted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx on your query.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx